# Custom DQL-Function not found

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to implement a custom DATE-function for DQL, here's there code:

```
namespace SwingBy\SwingByBundle\DQL; 

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;

/**
 * Date  ::= "DATE" "(" ArithmeticPrimary ")"
 */

class Date extends FunctionNode {

    public $dateTimeExpression = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser){

         $parser->match(Lexxer::T_IDENTIFIER);
         $parser->match(Lexxer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
         $this->dateTimeExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
         $parser->match(Lexxer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker){

        return "DATE(" . $this->dateTimeExpression . ")";
    }
}
```

here's the config in config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                date: SwingBy\SwingByBundle\DQL\Date
```

And here's the Error:

```
The autoloader expected class "SwingBy\SwingByBundle\DQL\Date" to be defined in file 
"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/swingby_dev2.3/src/SwingBy/SwingByBundle/DQL/Date.php". The 
file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a   
typo.
```

I am not able to find a solution, I've tried several different namespaces but nothing worked.

Symfony-version: 2.3

Comment: namespace SwingBy\SwingByBundle\DQL;

Comment: aleady tried it, still the same error

Comment: Unlikely.  The error message is clear.  Make sure you are looking at the right file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                dql:
                    datetime_functions:
                        date: SwingBy\SwingByBundle\DQL\Date
```

and/or try to add a backslash

> date: \SwingBy\SwingByBundle\DQL\Date

Comment: While it won't hurt, you really only need the entity_manages level if you are dealing with multiple entity managers.  And no, adding a back slash is neither required not will help.  The system knows that Date needs to be loaded and it knows the correct file.  He just has a typo somewhere.  What was posted in the question probably does not represent what is in the actual Date file.